# Simple Spring Cloud config server is not starting up-java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ConfigDataMissingEnvironmentPostProcessor

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, microservices, spring-cloud-config-server

I downloaded one config project from start.spring.io. added @EnableConfigServer added 3-4 properties git URI, application name and port but while starting up the server is not getting started. I tried with 3 different spring boot version, everywhere I am getting error. What can be done?

Here is the pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.10</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
      </parent>
      <groupId>com.photoapp</groupId>
      <artifactId>ConfigServer</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <name>ConfigServer</name>
      <description>ConfigServer</description>
      <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
      </properties>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </dependencyManagement>
    
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    
    </project>
```

**Application Config code:**

```
package com.photoapp;
    
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.cloud.config.server.EnableConfigServer;
    @EnableConfigServer  
    @SpringBootApplication  
    public class ConfigServerApplication   
    {   
        public static void main(String[] args) {    
            SpringApplication.run(ConfigServerApplication.class, args);
                
        }
    
    }
```

**Application.properties**

```
server.port=8012  
spring.application.name=ConfigServer  
#spring.profiles.active=native  
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/SubhankarMukherjee/PhotoAppConfiguration.git  
spring.cloud.config.server.git.username = ****  
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password = ****
```

I am getting beloe error. Tried all possible combination but not working at all

```
    19:10:46.131 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to instantiate org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor [org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServerConfigDataMissingEnvironmentPostProcessor]
        at org.springframework.boot.util.Instantiator.instantiate(Instantiator.java:131)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.util.Instantiator.instantiate(Instantiator.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.util.Instantiator.instantiate(Instantiator.java:103)
        at org.springframework.boot.env.ReflectionEnvironmentPostProcessorsFactory.getEnvironmentPostProcessors(ReflectionEnvironmentPostProcessorsFactory.java:72)
        at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.getEnvironmentPostProcessors(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:117)
        at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:99)
        at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:86)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:82)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:117)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:111)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:62)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:375)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1318)
        at com.photoapp.ConfigServerApplication.main(ConfigServerApplication.java:16)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cloud/commons/ConfigDataMissingEnvironmentPostProcessor
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:284)
        at org.springframework.boot.util.Instantiator$TypeSupplier$1.get(Instantiator.java:210)
        at org.springframework.boot.util.Instantiator.instantiate(Instantiator.java:125)
        ... 29 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cloud.commons.ConfigDataMissingEnvironmentPostProcessor
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 46 common frames omitted
    The error has started here.................
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to instantiate org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor [org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServerConfigDataMissingEnvironmentPostProcessor]
        at org.springframework.boot.util.Instantiator.instantiate(Instantiator.java:131)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.util.Instantiator.instantiate(Instantiator.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.util.Instantiator.instantiate(Instantiator.java:103)
        at org.springframework.boot.env.ReflectionEnvironmentPostProcessorsFactory.getEnvironmentPostProcessors(ReflectionEnvironmentPostProcessorsFactory.java:72)
        at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.getEnvironmentPostProcessors(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:117)
        at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:99)
        at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:86)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMul`enter code here`ticaster.java:143)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:82)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:117)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:111)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:62)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:375)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1318)
        at com.photoapp.ConfigServerApplication.main(ConfigServerApplication.java:16)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cloud/commons/ConfigDataMissingEnvironmentPostProcessor
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:284)
        at org.springframework.boot.util.Instantiator$TypeSupplier$1.get(Instantiator.java:210)
        at org.springframework.boot.util.Instantiator.instantiate(Instantiator.java:125)
        ... 29 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cloud.commons.ConfigDataMissingEnvironmentPostProcessor
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 46 more
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have a dependency missing in your pom.xml
try adding spring-cloud-commons:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-commons</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
</dependency>
```